# Limit question involving the recursion formula ${P_n} = {2^{{P_{n - 1}}}} - 1\forall n = 2,3,.....$

Tags: limits

Let ${P_n} = {2^{{P_{n - 1}}}} - 1\forall n = 2,3,.....$and let ${P_1} = {2^x} - 1$ then $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{{P_n}}}{x} = {\left( {\ell n\lambda } \right)^{kn}}$ where $\lambda+n$ is

My solution is as follow

${P_1} = {2^x} - 1$

${P_2} = {2^{{P_1}}} - 1 \Rightarrow {P_2} = {2^{{2^x} - 1}} - 1 = \frac{{{2^{{2^x}}} - 2}}{2}$

${P_3} = {2^{{P_2}}} - 1 = {2^{\frac{{{2^{{2^x}}} - 2}}{2}}} - 1 = \frac{{{2^{{2^{{2^x}}} - 1}} - 2}}{2}$

${P_4} = {2^{{P_3}}} - 1 = {2^{\frac{{{2^{{2^{{2^x}}} - 1}} - 2}}{2}}} - 1 = \frac{{{2^{{2^{{2^{{2^x}}} - 2}}}} - 2}}{2}$

${P_5} = {2^{{P_4}}} - 1 = {2^{\frac{{{2^{{2^{{2^{{2^x}}} - 2}}}} - 2}}{2}}} - 1 = \frac{{{2^{{2^{{2^{{2^{{2^x}}} - 3}}}}}} - 2}}{2}$

I am not able to solve further

Comment: Is $\ell n \lambda$ supposed to be $\ln (\lambda)$?  Since $n$ appears on the left, I took it to be $\ell \times n$.  Also, you trailed off in stating the problem, ending with "$\lambda +n$ is $\cdots$" without finishing.

Comment: In any case why not work this out for small $n$?  Perhaps those results will inform a general computation.

Comment: Hint: use $\frac{P_{n+1}}x=\frac{2^{P_n}-1}{P_n}\cdot\frac{P_n}x$ and induction.

Comment: This is an integer type question hence normally question end with these words